# Uk tier-4 dependent, proof of transfer for new funds available

Tags: visa, uk-visa

My dependent submitted the online application fee for her tier-4 dependent visa(applying at the same time) and attached a bank statement that has 25% less amount of what was actual required to show maintenance fee for her, maintained for 28days. Now she has got some more money in her account (When fee is already submitted), is there any benefit of attaching new bank statement showing this new amount when it is not maintained for 28 days? can we write in cover letter that we are ready to provide another letter to home office (if they require) anytime, showing that funds are still there.

Do they consider any explanations or its of no use?

Comment: Why did she apply knowing the documentation provided did not meet the requirements?

Comment: We thought that since the university is providing yearly bursary that cover mains applicant fully and still there is a amount remaining, we didn't submit complete maintenance amount for my spouse.

Now we read somewhere that even if the scholarship has amount for dependent, if it is not intended for her, it doesn't count towards her maintenance.

Comment: I propose to withdraw your request and submit again, if they have not started to process your application you get full refund. However, if I were you, I would have withdraw that anyway.